# Digital Globe WMTS won't work in MapInfo 12.0

Tags: mapinfo, wmts, maxar-digitalglobe

Digital Globe recently provide API and WMTS service to the public.

I follow the instruction in the https://mapsapi.digitalglobe.com/ and get the token here https://mapsapi.digitalglobe.com/account

In QGIS adding WMTS work like this: open the WMS dialogue and put the API link together with token ID provided by Digital Globe.

> http://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/digitalglobe/ciode6t5k0081aqm7k06dod4v/wmts?access_token="token
>   here"

In QGIS it work fine.  But in MapInfo when I put the same URL above to MapInfo WMS dialogue I get the error "Http status 422. Enable to retrieve capability form server".

Any one has successfully adding Digital Globe WMTS to MapInfo?
[image]

Comment: Is it really a WMS, or is it a WMTS?

Comment: Good point, @nmtoken! Looks like an WMTS service. If so, you will need MapInfo Pro 16.0. Do they provide a TMS service, too?

Comment: This is true, I just check the document, it is actually a WMTS. DigitalGlobe also provide TMS service, see here https://mapsapidocs.digitalglobe.com/docs/tiles . Is it possible to add TMS to MapInfo?